# Website displaying device CSS media queries to desktop PC

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, media-queries

I've tried searching for this in SO and google but just can't find a solution. I might not be searching using the right language.

I've got a responsive HTML5 template that I've got setup with CSS media queries to display differently to tablet/mobile. However I've found 2 computers that are displaying the web page using the tablet view I've got setup. They're a Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 OS(in any browser) and I've tested it on MANY other computers and they're the only computers that I'm able to reproduce this with.

I'm not sure what's happening here but it seems very unusual, it could be I've got the media queries setup incorrectly, but then why would it only occur on 2 computers?

Here are the media queries I've got setup:

```
/* Tablets (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* CSS CODE HERE */
}

/* Tablets (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* CSS CODE HERE */
}

/* Mobile (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 767px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* CSS CODE HERE */
}

/* Mobile (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 767px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* CSS CODE HERE */
}
```

These computers aren't at my current location so it's difficult to quickly test on them, but has anyone come across this? Or know what's going on here?

I appreciate any insight you can give me.

Comment: it looks like the resolution of the monitors is `1024px` so you need to change `max-device-width : 1024px` to `max-device-width : 1020px` and try

Comment: Oh, so media queries base the max-device-width off the screen resolution, not the browser size? Because I was wondering if that was the case, why the media queries don't become active if I resize my browser.

Comment: no it is because of the `only screen` is given to @media changing it to `@media screen` will also work when you resize your browser

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me with this one, I really appreciate it. Is there a way to target tablet/mobile and exclude desktop completely?

Comment: on which browsers you saw desktop taking ipad css?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=%40media